# Image is getting cut off when using the share dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I have the open graph tags setup for my site and have created an image that has the recommended dimensions of 1200x630.  When I use the the debug tool for my site, the image gets cut off.  I have tried a variety of different sizes but just can't figure it out.

My site is http://www.milehighinabox.com and you try it at the facebook debugger you can see the cutoff image

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Facebook decides what image size to display where, when and to whom – it can differ for different locations (timeline, newsfeed), and based on other factors. Only thing you can try, is specify multiple `og:image` including image dimensions, and make one of them a square one, in the hope that Facebook will choose that one when they display a small version; that way at least you can influence what part of the content will be visible.

Comment: I finally came across a thread that explained what was going  on.  While I was changing my image and trying different sizes, I was not changing the image name.  For the image cache to be cleared, I need to change the file name that I was using.  Once I did that, things worked as expected